# Rewrite one URL to another, and then block the first one using Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

#### Description:

I've changed with RewriteRules (no redirect) a typical PHP-like URL:

```
domain.com/script.php?parameter=value
```

to more friendly one:

```
domain.com/script/value
```

But I still can reach the same output using both the first and second URLs.

#### Problem to solve:

For security purposes and just because "I don't need one of them", I tried to block the first URL with a `403` response code using an `[F] flag` matching rule. The problem is that it also blocks the second URL.

#### Question:

Is there any possible way to accomplish this without blocking the second URL?
Is my thinking correct - should I ban the first URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *changing* an existing URL structure then you will need to *redirect* the old (ugly) URLs to the new (pretty) URLs, rather than reject them with a 403 response. If it's a brand new site then you could reject them with a 404 (`R=404`) - preferable to a 403 I think in this instance.

Something like the following (placed before your existing rewrites):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?parameter=([^\ ]*)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^script.php$ /script/%1? [R=301,L]
```

By comparing against `THE_REQUEST` we can make sure we only redirect HTTP requests (from the client) and not internal rewrites by Apache.

The `%1` in the `RewriteRule` substitution refers to the parenthesised sub pattern in the `RewriteCond` pattern. Whilst a question mark (`?`) at the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution removes the original query string from the request.

Comment: Code works fine, but I ve changed redirect to 404. Thanks for this tip I see this more particulary useful. Marked as best answer.